# ActionBar and ViewPager and CursorLoader works, but maybe there is better way

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, android-adapter

My application loads data from database (ContentResolver) and make tabs in ActionBar with ViewPager. The following code works as expected but I want someone to review my code. I need to know if it complies with the general patterns and practices? Does it need a change? Can I get some opinions?

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    TabAdapter tabAdapter;
    ViewPager viewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tabAdapter = new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabAdapter);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position)
            {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });


    }


    private class TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ActionBar.TabListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
    {
        ArrayList<String> lists = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();


        public TabAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager)
        {
            super(fragmentManager);

            getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

        }


        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
        {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());            
        }


        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
        {

        }


        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
        {

        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int arg0)
        {
            return fragments.get(arg0);
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return fragments.size();
        }


        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
        {
            return lists.get(position);
        }


        @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1)
        {
            CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    TasksContentProvider.TaskLists.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);

            return cursorLoader;
        }


        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor c)
        {
            while (c.moveToNext())
            {
                String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TasksContentProvider.TaskLists.Columns.TITLE));
                lists.add(title);
                TaskListFragment fragment = new TaskListFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("LIST_ID", c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(TasksContentProvider.TaskLists.Columns._ID)));
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                fragments.add(fragment);

                final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
                actionBar.removeAllTabs();
                for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++)
                {

                    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(getPageTitle(i)).setTabListener(this));
                }
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That completely depends on your design. If you are willing to use SherlockActionBar then you're likely to be dependent on Some one else's design/code. However you can find many exmaples and tutorials of how to make use of SherlockActionbar. However you'll find that there are many new modules that can be used to create similar functionality as of ActionbarSherlock. Please take a look at the following link to find new features in v4 and v7 libraries,

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Few suggestions on code structuring . Try to modularize your code even though as of now its readable. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using `mFragmentStatePageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`; in `onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data)` to notify changes of data, and if you move the cursor loader part to `MainActivity`, it also works. personally i prefer not to implements cursor loader in adapter.